# Where does react native store assets?

Tags: javascript, facebook, react-native, create-react-native-app

Hi I am developing a react native **android** app, and I noticed that video assets only work when the device is connected to the internet. That leads me to the question: where does react native store video assets?

To add clarity: I'm using the require syntax for local file (i.e : source={require('assets/file')}; so the files are all inside the actual directory of the folder)

Are the video assets being hosted on a hosting service? (If so, how does this work, why do they do this, and who is paying for this hosting? I'm definitely not paying for anything right now).

Finally, how can I get my videos to work offline? (I've been searching for days and haven't found any solution for this and no mention of this in the actual docs).

Comment: Were you able to get any resolution on this ?